# How to customize the eshell prompt?

Tags: shell, emacs

How can I customize the prompt of `eshell`? Specifically how can I prevent it from showing the full current path?

Comment: This is actually a valid question, given the lack of documentation in eshell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a lot of possibilities to customize a prompt in [the emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellFunctions#toc7).

In the following example only three last directory names of the path will be shown, the directories in the beginning will be shortened to one letter:

```
(setq eshell-prompt-function
      (lambda()
        (concat (getenv "USER") "@" (getenv "HOST") ":"
                ((lambda (p-lst)
                   (if (> (length p-lst) 3)
                       (concat
                        (mapconcat (lambda (elm) (substring elm 0 1))
                                   (butlast p-lst (- (length p-lst) 3))
                                   "/")
                        "/"
                        (mapconcat (lambda (elm) elm)
                                   (last p-lst (- (length p-lst) 3))
                                   "/"))
                     (mapconcat (lambda (elm) elm)
                                p-lst
                                "/")))
                 (split-string (eshell/pwd) "/"))
                (if (= (user-uid) 0) " # " " $ "))))
```

Comment: I tried this: (setq eshell-prompt-function (lambda () "> ")) 
in order to get a clean '>' but this breaks my tab completion and 'C-c C-a' to go to beginning of command - is there a way not to break this and also have a simple prompt?

Answer (score 0):

You must also set `eshell-prompt-regexp` to match what `eshell-prompt-function` returns or you'll have problems like [Palace Chan](https://superuser.com/users/155966/palace-chan) in the comment above this.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)